# Beginner question about declaring and assigning instance fields constructor

Tags: java

So I've started learning Java a couple weeks back, and there is one concept I can't quite grasp why it has to be done.

For example;

```
public class House {
  String color;

  public House(String houseColor) {
       color = houseColor;
 }
}
```

Why do you need to declare a String in the class, and pass in a String into the constructor. And then assign the declared variable to the other string ? I do understand that when you don't do this and try to print out the variable, it gives you the memory address. But I just can't see why you would need to assign color to `houseColor`.

If anyone could explain this to me at the most basic level, I would be very thankfull.

Comment: This is a good reference to review about constructors in Java, but conceptually can be expanded to other programming languages as well!
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/constructors-in-java/

Comment: Please remember that the constructor should have the same name as the class (now the class is named House and the constructor Car)

Comment: FYI, I fixed your code to comply with Java naming conventions. The names of classes start with an uppercase letter. The names of methods and variable start with a lowercase letter. So `houseColor`, not `HouseColor`. Following these conventions will make your code easier to read, and will even help understand the answer to your Question.

Comment: I also fixed your constructor name, `House`, not `Car`. Take more care with copy-editing before you post.

Comment: Note that when you print the variable what you see is _not_ the memory address. It's just a hashcode generated by the system when the object was created. It's not even guaranteed to be unique. The JVM may move objects around in memory during their lifetime, so they don't have a constant memory address.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing a bit. What you did was to define an instance field called `color` of type String and assign it the value of `houseColor` when the constructor is called. This will allow you to reference `color` in any instance method inside class `House`.

If you didn't do this, you wouldn't be able to access the value of `houseColor` in the `House` class, except inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have a class 'house'.  Think of this as a general contract for what a house is/does - this is how Object-Oriented programming works.

You have declared an *instance* field, `String color`.  The fact that this is an *instance* field (instead of `static`) is saying that any *single* house has a colour (which makes sense).  But you have not *made* any houses yet, you've just declared what a house is/does.

When you want to actually *create* a house, you call a constructor.  It is at *this* point that you can tell the program what *that specific* house's colour is, by passing it into the constructor.  The constructor then stores the provided value in its field, to say that the given color is now that house's colour.  When the constructor finishes, a new house instance has been created (with the given colour).  If you want *more* houses, with different colours, you would then call the constructor again, with different values, and all of the returned houses have those given colours.

If you do *not* assign a value to that field, then it will be `null`.  This *could* be meaningful to you, for example, if you decided that that meant you had a transparent house.  But, in general, I think it's safe to say most houses have a colour of some form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Constructor of a class have the same name as that of class like :

```
public class House {
String color;

public House (String houseColor) {
   color = houseColor;
 }
}
```

you can have empty argument constructor or else you can have constructor with arguments.

Basically Constructor is used to instantiate the instance variables of the class, so, which is "String color" in your case.